# Context Free Grammar for unsigned real numbers

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

Construct Context-free Grammar for unsigned real numbers with coma. Each 
number has the same number of digits before the decimal and after decimal. Example: 0,0; 0090,1117; 1,9; are correct, but 0,00; 90,1117; 1,90; , are incorrect.
I have something like this:

(real) ::= (digit) (digit) (decimal part)

(digit*) ::= (digit) (digit*) | epsilon

(decimal part) ::= ',' (digit) (digit*) | epsilon

(digit) ::= 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9

I know it's incorrect, because my syntax allows 1,90, but I have no idea how to fix this. Please, help me :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate the integer and decimal parts simultaneously:

$$\text{(real)}::=\text{(digit)},\text{(digit)}\mid\text{(digit)}\text{(real)}\text{(digit)}$$

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thank you :)

Comment: @GrimGirl: You’re welcome.